# Invalid column name in sql server with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

WHEN I try to run the SQL it is not formatting the @Status parameter' value with single quotes since it is text. Hence it is giving this error as **Running** is invalid column name.

```
DECLARE
    @ID int,
    @Status varchar(150),
    @StandardOutput varchar(max) = NULL,
    @StandardError varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Query Varchar(max),
    @S1 varchar(max),
    @S2 varchar(max),
    @S3 varchar(max)


SET     @Status = N'Running'
SET     @StandardError = N'So2234'
SET     @StandardOutput = Null
SET @S1 = ''
SET @ID = 1
--DECLARE @S1 varchar(max)
--SET @S1 = N' '
IF @Status IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @S1 = ( N',  dbo.JobQueue.Status = ' + @Status);
    END
IF @StandardError IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @S1 = @S1 + N',  dbo.JobQueue.StandardError = ' + @StandardError
    END
IF @StandardOutput IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @S1 = N', dbo.JobQueue.StandardOutput = ' + @StandardOutput
    END

SET @S1 = (N' UPDATE  dbo.JobQueue SET ' + SUBSTRING(@S1, 2, LEN(@s1)) ) + ' ';
SET @S1 = @S1 + N' WHERE  dbo.JobQueue.ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ID);
SELECT @S1
EXEC(@S1)
```

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Running'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line  1
Invalid column name 'So2234'

RESULT OF PRINT @S1

```
UPDATE  dbo.JobQueue SET   dbo.JobQueue.Status = Running,  dbo.JobQueue.StandardError = So2234  WHERE  dbo.JobQueue.ID = 1
```

Comment: could you share theresults when you PRINT @S1?

Comment: I have updated with print @S1 Result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these values are known by you and not provided by a UI somewhere, you can escape it manually.
However, don't do this if the 'Running' value isn't constant but is provided by a UI (SQL Injection)

Try this:

```
IF @Status IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
    SET @S1 = ( N',  dbo.JobQueue.Status = ''' + @Status + ''');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the result from `SELECT @S1`.

There must be a syntax error on it! For example, spaces or quotes missing somewhere usually are the main reason.

---

Update:

```
UPDATE  dbo.JobQueue SET   dbo.JobQueue.Status = Running,  dbo.JobQueue.StandardError = So2234  WHERE  dbo.JobQueue.ID = 1
```

Running and So2234 prolly are text data types, so you're missing quotes on them!

Comment: yes it is missing quotes but while setting @s1 it is specified in quotes and when it is getting generated as SQL it is removing them.

Comment: `SET     @Status = N'"Running"'`
`SET     @StandardError = N'"So2234"'`
Try changing to this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use non-dynamic sql here?

```
UPDATE jq
SET Status = ISNULL(@status, jq.Status)
    ,StandardError = ISNULL(@StandardError, jq.StandardError)
    ,StandardOutput = ISNULL(@StandardOutput, jq.StandardOutput)      
FROM dbo.JobQueue jq
WHERE jq.ID = @id
```

Comment: Oh! So I don't have to worry about Null values this way.  This should take care I guess right.  This would be amazing.